# Can I download different versions of a Flutter app with different application IDs to a single project in Google and Apple developer consoles?

Tags: flutter, dart, app-store-connect, google-play-console, android-build-flavors

In my project, I have configured flutter flavors to run my application from different environments. Faced with the difficulty of downloading their applications in the developer console google and apple store. Since I have several application IDs (id.dev (for development), id.staging (for testing), id (release version)), do I need to create 3 projects in the developer console or can I somehow download versions for development and testing (and they have a different application id) to a project that was created with the application ID for the product environment?

```
productFlavors {
        development {
            dimension "default"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "flavor2"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev" <- for development
        }
        staging {
            dimension "default"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "flavor3"
            applicationIdSuffix ".stg" <- for testing
        }
        production {
            dimension "default"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "flavor1"
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            applicationId "id" <- production
        }
    }
```